# HTML5 canvas continuously stroking lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw some continuously growing lines in HTML5 and Javascript. Here is what I want to do:

A point located at the center of my screen will have 3 lines growing (120 degree to each other) to a certain length, say 50 pix, then each of this 3 vertex will become a new center and have another 3 lines.

(I couldnt post images due to low reputation I have, hopefully you know what I mean abt the image here...)

I already written the function to have a array of all the points I need as the centers, starting from the center of my screen. I am thinking to write a loop over this array to draw the lines. I DO NOT want to directly use the stroke so that the line just appears on the screen. I want to have something like the the lines are drawn bit by bit (bad english here, please excuse my english) until it reaches the pre-defined length. However my code dont work quite well here, it only displays all the center points and only the last center point has the movement to have the 3 lines to grow...

I need to know the correct way to do this... many thanks in advance!

(please ignore the variable time or startTime in my code... )

```
<script>
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.width= window.innerWidth;
canvas.height= window.innerHeight;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var totalLength = 50;

var centreSet = new Array();
var counter = 0;

var centre = {
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2,
};

var myLine = {
    length : 0,
    color : 'grey',
    lineWidth : 0.5,
};

function drawLine(centre, context, mylength) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(centre.x, centre.y);
    context.lineTo(centre.x, centre.y - mylength);
    context.moveTo(centre.x, centre.y);
    context.lineTo(centre.x - 0.866 * mylength, centre.y + mylength/2);
    context.moveTo(centre.x, centre.y);
    context.lineTo(centre.x + 0.866 * mylength, centre.y + mylength/2);
    context.lineWidth = myLine.lineWidth;
    context.strokeStyle = myLine.color;
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
}

function startAnimate(centre, canvas, context, startTime, mylength) {
        // update
    var time = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
    var linearSpeed = 5;
    // pixels / second
    var newX = linearSpeed / 10;

    if(mylength < totalLength) {
        mylength = mylength + newX;
        // clear
        //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawLine(centre, context, mylength);

        // request new frame
        requestAnimFrame(function() {
            startAnimate(centre, canvas, context, startTime, mylength);
        });
    }

}

function animate(centre, canvas, context, startTime){
            //create array to have all the center points
    centreSet = getCentres(); 
    for (var i = 0; i < centreSet.length; i++){
                    //pass the x and y values in a object for each center we have in the array
        centre.x = str2x(centreSet[i]);
        centre.y = str2y(centreSet[i]);
        startAnimate(centre, canvas, context, startTime, 0);
    }
}

    setTimeout(function() {
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    animate(centre, canvas, context, startTime);
}, 1000);
```

---

I just edited your code, I added the following part:

```
var length = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 380; i++){
window.setTimeout(function() {drawFrame(length);},16.67);
length = length + 0.25; 
}
```

I expect the screen appears to draw the incremental lines bit by bit until it reaches the length I want. However, it seems like the whole incremental process is not shown and it only shows the finished drawing.

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding your followup question about why your animation loop fails**

By putting your setTimeout in a for-loop, each new setTimeout is cancelling the previous setTimeout.

So you’re just left with the very last setTimeout running to completion.

In an animation loop, you typically do 3 things during each "frame":

1. Change some data to reflect how the new frame is different from the previous frame.
2. Draw the frame.
3. Test if the animation is complete. If not, do another frame (go to #1).

The `setTimeout` function is used to do the last part of #3 (do another frame)

So **setTimeout is really acting as your animation loop**. --- Your for-loop is not needed.

This is how you would restructure your code to follow this pattern:

```
var length=0;
var maxLength=50;

function draw(){

    // make the line .25 longer
    length=length+.25;

    // draw
    drawFrame(length);

    // test if the line is fully extended
    // if not, call setTimeout again
    // setTimeout(draw,100) will call this same draw() function in 100ms
    if(length<maxLength){
        setTimeout(draw,100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Edited: to include spawning of child objects after lines reach terminal distance]**

In your code you were not spawning new center points when the lines reached their maximum extension.

I would suggest that each of your centre objects have at least this much information in order to spawn a new set of centre objects when their lines reach terminal length:

```
var newCentrePoint={
    x:x,
    y:y,
    maxLength:newMaxLength,
    growLength:growLength,
    currentLength:0,
    isActive:true
}
```

The x,y are the centerpoint’s coordinates.

maxLength is the maximum extension of the 3 lines before they are terminated.

growLength is the amount by which each line will grow in each new frame.

currentLength is the current length of the line.

isActive is a flag indicating if this point is growing lines (true) or if it’s terminated (false)

Then when each line reaches terminal length you can spawn a new set of lines like this:

```
// spawns 3 new centre points – default values are for testing
function spawn(point,newMaxLength,newColor,growLength,newLineWidth){
    var max=newMaxLength||point.maxLength/2;
    var color=newColor|| (colors[++colorIndex%(colors.length)]);
    var grow=growLength||point.growLength/2;
    var lw=newLineWidth||point.lineWidth-1;

    // new center points are spawned at the termination points of the 3 current lines
    newPoint((point.x),(point.y-point.maxLength),max,color,grow,lw);
    newPoint((point.x-0.866*point.maxLength),(point.y+point.maxLength/2),max,color,grow,lw);
    newPoint((point.x+0.866*point.maxLength),(point.y+point.maxLength/2),max,color,grow,lw);
}

// creates a new point object and puts in the centreSet array for processing
function newPoint(x,y,newMaxLength,newColor,growLength,newLineWidth){
    var newPt={
        x:x,
        y:y,
        maxLength:newMaxLength,
        color:newColor,
        lineWidth:newLineWidth,
        growLength:growLength,
        currentLength:0,
        isActive:true
    }
    centreSet.push(newPt);
}
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Vc8Gf/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // colors
    var colors=["red","blue","gold","purple","green"];
    var colorIndex=0;

    //
    var centreSet=[]
    var generations=1;

    // seed point
    newPoint(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2,100,"red",15);

    // start 
    draw();

    //
    function draw(){
        //
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        //
        for(var i=0;i<centreSet.length;i++){
            //
            var centre=centreSet[i];


            //
            if(centre.isActive){
                // 
                centre.currentLength+=centre.growLength;
                //
                if(centre.currentLength>=centre.maxLength){
                    centre.isActive=false;
                    centre.currentLength=centre.maxLength;
                    spawn(centre);
                }
            }
            //
            drawLines(centre);
        }
        //
        if(generations<120){
            setTimeout(draw,500);
        }else{
            context.font="18pt Verdana";
            context.fillText("Finished 120 generations",40,350);
        }
    }


    function spawn(point,newMaxLength,newColor,growLength,newLineWidth){
        var max=newMaxLength||point.maxLength/2;
        var color=newColor|| (colors[++colorIndex%(colors.length)]);
        var grow=growLength||point.growLength/2;
        var lw=newLineWidth||point.lineWidth-1;
        newPoint((point.x),(point.y-point.maxLength),max,color,grow,lw);
        newPoint((point.x-0.866*point.maxLength),(point.y+point.maxLength/2),max,color,grow,lw);
        newPoint((point.x+0.866*point.maxLength),(point.y+point.maxLength/2),max,color,grow,lw);
        generations++;
    }

    function newPoint(x,y,newMaxLength,newColor,growLength,newLineWidth){
        var newPt={
            x:x,
            y:y,
            maxLength:newMaxLength,
            color:newColor,
            lineWidth:newLineWidth,
            growLength:growLength,
            currentLength:0,
            isActive:true
        }
        centreSet.push(newPt);
    }


    function drawLines(centre) {

        var length=centre.currentLength;
        //
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(centre.x, centre.y);
        context.lineTo(centre.x, centre.y - length);
        //
        context.moveTo(centre.x, centre.y);
        context.lineTo(centre.x - 0.866 * length, centre.y + length/2);
        //
        context.moveTo(centre.x, centre.y);
        context.lineTo(centre.x + 0.866 * length, centre.y + length/2);
        //
        context.strokeStyle=centre.color;
        context.lineWidth = centre.lineWidth;
        context.stroke();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi Mark, I am wondering where I did wrong in my code since the resulting output shows all the center points and the incremental drawing for the last point..

Comment: Greetings!  In your code, your centre objects can be extended to include enough data to spawn 3 child centre objects after the lines reach terminal distance.  I added to my answer to illustrate how.

Comment: In my code, I already had an array which contains all the center points that it needs to spawn 3 lines, it is in the aminate(), centreSet = getCentres();